# CreateWindow Fails as Unable to Find Window Class - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, createwindow

In my application the function `CreateWindow` is failing for some reason.  `GetLastError` indicates error 1407, which, according to the MSDN documentation is "Cannot find window class."  The following code shows how `CreateWindow` is being called and the respective variables names at time of call:

```
m_hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle( NULL );

if ( m_hInstance == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to retrieve the module handle.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}

m_hWnd = ::CreateWindow(
    _pwcWindowClass,    // L"USBEventNotificationWindowClass"
    _pwcWindowName,     // L"USBEventNotificationWindow"
    WS_ICONIC,
    0,
    0,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    m_hInstance,        // 0x00400000
    NULL
    );

if ( m_hWnd == NULL )   // m_hWnd is returned as NULL and exception is thrown.
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to create window.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}

::ShowWindow( m_hWnd, SW_HIDE );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633587%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) before you can use the window class on CreateWindow.

Example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633575%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> Each process must register its own
>   window classes. To register an
>   application local class, use the
>   RegisterClassEx function. You must
>   define the window procedure, fill the
>   members of the WNDCLASSEX structure,
>   and then pass a pointer to the
>   structure to the RegisterClassEx
>   function.

Comment: Make sure that you are also using the same hinstance in the RegisterClassEx and WindowsCreateEx